# Why can't I access this Facebook game in Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04

Can anyone please explain to me why I can't access this game using Mozilla Firefox on Ubuntu?

https://apps.facebook.com/livepool/?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0

Comment: I can access it without trouble. Can you please tell me more; what happens when you try opening it?

Comment: Hey I noticed you're using 13.04! It's not supported anymore! you should upgrade to 13.10 from your "software updater"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Adobe Flash (where all the FB games are build on), has it's own flash-plugin for ubuntu, but sometimes you also have a 3-party plugin for flash on Firefox.

Try the following;

1. open up a terminal
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove flashplugin-installer`
3. `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

restart Firefox and check again. should be working now.